# What is the purpose of the .enfold() method in the context of Datetime objects and timezones?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, python-dateutil

I am continuing to practice on Data Camp and the current session covers Datetimes, timezone, dateutil, etc. However, there is a function I am not sure about. The function mentioned in the below code is `.enfold()` and I cannot seem to locate an easy explanation in the documentation. What is its general purpose and what is it doing in the Data Camp practice code below?

```
trip_durations = []
for trip in onebike_datetimes:
  # When the start is later than the end, set the fold to be 1
  if trip['start'] > trip['end']:
    trip['end'] = tz.enfold(trip['end'])
  # Convert to UTC
  start = trip['start'].astimezone(tz.gettz('UTC'))
  end = trip['end'].astimezone(tz.gettz('UTC'))

  # Subtract the difference
  trip_length_seconds = (end-start).total_seconds()
  trip_durations.append(trip_length_seconds)

# Take the shortest trip duration
print("Shortest trip: " + str(min(trip_durations)))
```

I tried finding the documenatation for `enfold` directly under `datetime` documentation for Python but it kept mentioning "fold" under each of the functions/methods for the datetime package. Not super explanatory, so more information regarding `.enfold()` and "fold" in general would be helpful.

Comment: How is `tz` defined in this code?

Comment: As far as I'm aware the tz part is from the dateutil package - I'm not 100% sure what it is referencing.

Comment: There is no "general" meaning of `enfold`, I've removed that part from the title of the question.

Comment: see[dateutil.tz.enfold(dt, fold=1)](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tz.html) for explanation

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that `enfold` in your code is the function from the `tz` module in the third-party `timezone` package: https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tz.html#dateutil.tz.enfold

As the documentation mentions, "fold" is an attribute of datetime objects whose implementation was changed in Python 3.6 by [PEP 495](https://peps.python.org/pep-0495/). I cannot explain better what "fold" means than what is described in that document (unless my example below counts).

Apparently "fold" existed before Python 3.6, but was used/accessed in a different way. The `tz.enfold` function exists to unify the programming interface to the "fold" attribute regardless of the Python version used.

---

The specific application of "fold" in this code example seems to be the calculation of trip durations with "start" and "end" times. If an "end" time is found which seems to be earlier than the "start" time, it is deduced that the "end" time was recorded after a timezone change has occurred where the clocks were turned back by 1 hour, and the time is to be interpreted as the *later* of the two possible "real" times with that "local" or "wall" time. `enfold(trip["end"])` returns a datetime object with the same local time as `trip["end"]` but with "fold" set to 1.

Example: Clocks are turned back at 3 AM to 2 AM

```
      1 AM    2 AM    3 AM   (4 AM)
-------|-------|--F-S--| - - - | - - > old local time
                      /
                    /
                  /
                /
 - - - | - - - |--E----|-------|-----> new local time
     (1 AM)   2 AM    3 AM    4 AM

S: start     - 2:40 AM (old local time)
E: end       - 2:20 AM (new local time, fold=1, 40 minutes later than S)
F: false end - 2:20 AM (old local time, fold=0, 20 minutes earlier than S)
```